# ASPC C# - (500) Internal Server Error when posting JSON

Tags: json, webrequest

I am trying to POST some JSON data to a remote server and read JSON response back from the remote server. My code is jumping in to the catch exception block with the error ex = {"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."} when it gets to this line near the bottom:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I have read a few posts on this forum and tried the code other suggest but I don't understand/can't get it to work.

Please can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? You can see my previous attempt which is commented out near the bottom of the code block.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
// include
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HobbsDPDJSONLibrary;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DPDAPILibrary
{
    public class DPD_API
    {
        #region public class variables
        private static string dpdapiun = "xxx";
        private static string dpdapipw = "xxx";
        private static string dpdAccountNumber = "xxx";
        private static string dpdapihost = "api.dpd.co.uk";
        private static string dpdapiinserttestshipment = "https://api.dpd.co.uk/shipping/shipment?test=true";
        private static string dpdapiinsertshipment = "https://api.dpd.co.uk/shipping/shipment";
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Send consignment data to the DPD API to create a shipment and return a consignment number (if successful).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="geoClientData"></param>
        /// <param name="JSONData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Boolean insertShipment(string geoSession, bool test, out string JSONdata)
        {
            try
            {
                // default output values
                JSONdata = "";
                bool returnValue = false;

                #region create new insert shipment object
                // a large block of code here that serialises a class into JSON, this bit works so I have omitted it to reduce the code I post on the forum
                #endregion

                string InsertShipmentData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewShipmentObject);

                // convert the 'insert shipment' JSON data to byte array for posting
                //byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InsertShipmentData);

                // set the target uri for the insert shipment request (defaults to test, or switch to live as per input parameter)
                Uri targetURI = new Uri(dpdapiinserttestshipment);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dpdapiinserttestshipment);
                if(!test)
                {
                    targetURI = new Uri(dpdapiinsertshipment);
                    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dpdapiinsertshipment);
                }

                // add headers to the web request for inserting a new shipment
                request.Host = dpdapihost;
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Timeout = 30000;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                request.Headers["GEOClient"] = "thirdparty/" + dpdAccountNumber;
                request.Headers["GeoSession"] = geoSession;

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(InsertShipmentData);
                }
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                //// run the request and read the response header
                //using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                //{
                //    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                //    {
                //        JSONdata = Convert.ToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
                //    }

                //    // check if OK (status 200) returned
                //    if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                //    {
                //        returnValue = true;
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        returnValue = false;
                //    }
                //    return returnValue;
                //}

                return returnValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                JSONdata = Convert.ToString(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```